# unpack/relocate textures to a folder other than ./texture

Tags: packed-data

If I unpack a blender file, it creates a folder called "texture", that is within the current folder.  Instead I'd like to default the unpack to a folder the is common across many 3d applications that I use (example: Documents/3d/textures).  I might be overlooking a Preferences setting.

This could also help me migrate previous blend files that might have used some other folder structure (pack and then unpack to my new structure).

[image]

[image]

Comment: As useful as that would be, I'm afraid this functionality isn't in yet :)

Comment: Thanks, Jachym Michal, I'm off to https://devtalk.blender.org to waste my time, LOL

Comment: Did anyone get anywhere with this question?  I'd also like to add that if you have files with duplicate filenames, Blender will effectively delete all but one of them.  Worse, those will still show up fine in the viewport until you revert or reload the file.  If that's months later, those files are now gone and you are S.O.L.

Comment: @ZachExchange -- i recently saw a developer post a comment at https://devtalk.blender.org/t/unpack-relocate-textures-to-a-folder-other-than-texture/18379/2 which is an exact copy of the above.   Comment was "wrong website" for suggestions